# Why does my Qt application lock up when I use QProcess or popen?

Tags: qt, fork

My Qt application is locking up with high cpu usage after running correctly for a few hours, and I'm trying to figure out why. This is on an embedded linux system.

The first thing I did was attach gdb and look at a stack backtrace. It shows the lockup occurring in ptmalloc_lock_all(), which is called by fork(). The application uses system() to play a video, and periodically uses QProcess to check whether a USB drive is mounted.

I don't intentionally use multiple threads in my application, but gdb shows 4 threads at the point where the freeze occurs. I've included the backtrace for all 4 threads:

```
(gdb) thread apply all backtrace

Thread 4 (Thread 995):
#0  0x4282dc50 in select () from /opt/filesys/fs/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x4246a768 in qt_safe_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval const*) ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#2  0x4246f2a8 in QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::doSelect(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>, timeval*) ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0x4246f6e0 in QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0x42435898 in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0x42435bac in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#6  0x42317834 in QThread::exec() ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#7  0x4231aaf8 in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
#8  0x4231aaf8 in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 3 (Thread 973):
#0  0x425c64bc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /opt/filesys/fs/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x413f8688 in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
#2  0x413f8688 in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtWebKit.so.4
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 2 (Thread 949):
#0  0x4282dc50 in select () from /opt/filesys/fs/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x4240c16c in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Cannot access memory at address 0x3054
#2  0x4240c16c in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Cannot access memory at address 0x3054
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 1 (Thread 720):
#0  0x427e1194 in ptmalloc_lock_all () from /opt/filesys/fs/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x428041c4 in fork () from /opt/filesys/fs/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x4240fce8 in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0x4240fce8 in ?? ()
   from /opt/filesys/fs/opt/filesys/fs/opt/qt/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I'm not very experienced with multithreaded programming, but from reading online it sounds like it can be dangerous to use fork() in a multithreaded application. I'm not sure what to do as an alternative though.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Marlon

Comment: All of those frames are from the Qt framework. Do you have gdb installed on the embedded system or are you copying over a core dump? Are you compiling your app with debug symbols? Do you have `-fomit-frame-pointer` turned on? What kind of embedded system is this? ARM? Or x86?

Comment: Also, how are you generating that backtrace? Are you attaching to the running process and `ctrl+c`ing?

Comment: I installed gdbserver on the embedded system and I'm connecting to it with gdb on my desktop. I compiled the app on my desktop with -g, but the version on the embedded system doesn't have any debug symbols. I haven't used -fomit-frame-pointer. It's an ARM system.

Comment: I generated the backtrace by running gdbserver --attach on my embedded system, connecting to it on my desktop using "target remote", and then running "thread apply all backtrace".